# How to edit a JList item text by double clicking on it?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList populated with Strings. I want to be able to edit an item by double clicking on it and then edit its text in the JList itself. So if I click an item, then it's highlighted and I see the cursor, then for example I delete the text and write something else. Then I click enter and the text is edited successfully. Is that possible & how can I do this please? I really need this.

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) It would probably be easier to pop the current value in a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` and if not the same when the dialog is dismissed, change the value in the model.

Answer (score 2):

See [List Editor](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/list-editor/) for a couple of solutions, one is to just use a JTable, the other is to create a custom edit Action for the JList.