# How to make an AbstractListModel subclass react to a Collection change?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList and I would like to supply it with my own ListModel. I have a LinkedHashMap that contains entries. I subclassed the AbstractListModel. What I would like to achieve is that whenever I remove an element from the Map, I want that to be reflected in the JList (adding or removing elements or even updating).

**EDIT-** the scenario of what I'm trying to do so is the following: I have a JList and add, edit and delete JButtons. I maintain a Map that contains Detectors objects. When I click the add button I want to add to the Map a new Detector object and at the same time I want the JList to be reflected with the new add. The same for edit and delete.

Here's what I've made so far, but I don't know how to make the Model response to the updates:

```
private class DetectorsListModel extends AbstractListModel {

        private List<Detector> detectors;
        private Map<Long, Detector> detectorsMap;

        public DetectorsListModel( Map<Long, Detector> detectorsMap) {
            this.detectorsMap = detectorsMap;
            detectors = new LinkedList<Detector>();
            for ( Long detectorID : detectorsMap.keySet() ) {
                detectors.add( detectorsMap.get(detectorID) );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return detectors.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Detector getElementAt(int index) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return detectors.get(index);
        }


    }
```

Please help!

Comment: You need to invoke the appropriate fireXXX method of the AbstractListModel.

Comment: I don't see any `JList` in your code.  That said, assuming you actually meant the `List` in your example, just don't give direct access to your `Map`.  That way any calls to your `DetectorsListModel` to update the map can update the `List` in the same method.

Comment: and your XxxListModel isn't complete, search here in post [java+swing+jlist+abstractlistmodel](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20[swing]%20[jlist]%20abstractlistmodel)

Comment: @StormeHawke I made an edit to the post.

Comment: Your model needs to have add/remove methods that you invoke when you click your buttons. Then the model updates the Map and invokes the appropriate fireXXX method. I'm not about to write the code for you. The last time I gave you an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212232/how-to-edit-a-jlist-item-text-by-double-clicking-on-it) you didn't appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using and adding new values to the map directly, you should use the model and add values to the model, which is responsible for adding the values to the underlying map *and* fire the appropriate events to refresh the table view:

```
public void add(Detector detector) {
    this.detectorsMap.put(detector.getId(), detector);
    this.detectors.add(detector);
    fireIntervalAdded(detectors.size() - 1, detectors.size() - 1);
}
```

Note that it would probably be easier to reconstruct a new map from the list of detectors when needed, to avoid maintaining two parallel collections.